# 403 Response when making 'ajax' call to web api

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, jsonp, fiddler

I am making calls to my backend to populate an observableArray like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'www.data.net/api/....',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        dataHolder(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Backend method:

```
    [Route("Api/mydata/GetMyContent/{postPageName}"), HttpGet]
           public HttpResponseMessage GetMyContent(string postPageName)
            {
                var result = mydataRepository.GetMyContent(postPageName);
                return Request.CreateResponse(result == null ? HttpStatusCode.OK :             
                       HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, result);
    }
```

Comment: This is likely a backend issue. Can you pots the webapi method you are calling.

Comment: @WayneEllery Ellery I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your backend method only returns "200 - OK" if the page you selected has no content. Otherwise if the page has some content you always return 403.

I kinda feel that you just might have inadvertently changed your ternary operator?

Maybe try:

```
    return Request.CreateResponse(result == null ? HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                                  HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
result == null ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
```

to

```
result != null ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
```